# Extracting nth character till the end of string in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the nth character onwards in a string, using R.  Here's my data:

```
StringField
example_string1
example_string2
example_string3
example_string4
example_string5
example_string6
example_string7
example_string8
example_string9
example_string10
example_string11
example_string12
```

I want to extract only the numbers after example_string, so the result would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9 
10
11
12
```

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
df$unique_number <- substr(df$stringField, 15:)
```

to indicate I want everything from the 15th position onward, till the end of the string.  Is there an easy way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: To revise your code minimally, just replace `substr` with `substring`, i.e. `substring(df$stringField, 15)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
x <- "example_string10"
substr(x, 15, 20)
#> [1] "10"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `substr` and `substring` can apply on a vector. It doesn't need to use `map`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, thank you for the hint. By coincidence I was going through the purrr primer at RStudio and was learning about functional programming, it seemed to fit.  But `substr` is the simplest solution to me. But you are right. I will delete the second part of the post.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy option using `sub`.  We can capture the final digits in the input, and then replace with only that captured quantity.

```
x <- "example_string10"
num <- sub("^.*?(\\d+)$", "\\1", x)
num

[1] "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in extracting only numbers from a string, this can be a solution:

```
library(stringr)

as.numeric(str_extract(df$stringField,"\\d+"))
```

Comment: Hey~`str_extract` can apply on a vector, so it doesn't need to use `sapply`, i.e. `as.numeric(str_extract(df$stringField, "\\d+"))`, right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I do not know why I added the `sapply`. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Replace each non-digit (`\D`) with an empty string and convert to numeric:

```
transform(df, unique_number = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", StringField)))
```

### Note

We used this as input:

```
df <- data.frame(StringField = c("example_string1", "example_string2",
  "example_string3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% tidyr::extract(StringField, into = "nmb", "([0-9]+)")
```